# Is the set $(-3,3]$ open in $(-4,3]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is $(-3,3]$ open in $(-4,3]$?

I thought that there has a neighbourhood of $3$ that is in $(-3,3]$,since right of $3$ has nothing. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, because $(-3, 3] = (-4, 3] \cap (-3, 4)$.

Comment: What is the topology? Once you carefully look at how topology is defined you should be able to answer such question by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find an open set in the topology you are studying $O$ such that $O$ $\cap$ $(-4,3]=(−3,3]$ then yes it is.